# Add spaces to the beginning of each matching line

Tags: vim, sed, awk, text-editing

For example, if I had a line that started at the beginning, and needed it to line up with the preceeding line, how could I do that most effectively.

```
      preceeding line
line I need to add spaces to
```

So it looks like this:

```
       predeeding line
       where it needs to start.
```

Its exactly 8 spaces away from where it needs to start. How could I do this with vim, awk or sed or another tool?

Other requirements/notes:

These lines occur multiple times in my file and I only want to make the changes between lines 100-500.

Comment: Do you want all lines indented by 8 spaces?  Or, do you want to match the indent on the preceding line?  What if two or more non-indented lines appear in a row: should only the first be given an indent?  Or, do they all get indents?

Comment: Match the indent from the preceeding line. There should not be any non-indented lines that preceed the line I want to add, as long as we can match exactlly on the preceeding line.

Comment: Let me clarify - there should not be any non-indented lines that would interfere, as long as we can match on the indented line to make the modification to the line below it.

Comment: This looks like a simple case for Vim's [auto indent](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code).  What happens when you start below the line with the correct indentation and call `==`?  To do this to 100-500 start at line 101 (assuming 100 has the correct indent) and then type `399==` to auto indent the next 399 line like the one above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file1
      preceeding line
line I need to add spaces to
    preceeding line
  preceeding line
line I need to add spaces to
```

The following indents the non-indented lines to match the indent of the previous line:

```
$ awk '{if (/^[^ \t]/) $0=x $0; else {x=$0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", x);}} 1' file1
      preceeding line
      line I need to add spaces to
    preceeding line
  preceeding line
  line I need to add spaces to
```

#### How it works

- `if (/^[^ \t]/) $0=x $0; else {x=$0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", x);}`

  If the line starts with neither a blank nor a tab, the add the indent `x` to the start of the line.

  Else, save the indentation from the current line in variable `x`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Multi-line version

For those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
    {
        if (/^[^ \t]/) 
           $0=x $0
        else { 
            x=$0
            sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", x)
        }
    } 

    1' file1
```

#### Restricting the changes to lines 100 through 500

```
awk 'NR>=100 && NR<=500 {if (/^[^ \t]/) $0=x $0; else {x=$0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", x);}} 1' file1
```

#### Changing the file in-place

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'NR>=100 && NR<=500 {if (/^[^ \t]/) $0=x $0; else {x=$0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", x);}} 1' file1
```

Using BSD/OSX awk:

```
 awk 'NR>=100 && NR<=500 {if (/^[^ \t]/) $0=x $0; else {x=$0; sub(/[^ \t].*/, "", x);}} 1' file1 >tmp && mv tmp file1
```

Answer (score 3):

In vim:

```
:100,500g/^[^ ]/normal 0ky^jP
```

Explanation:

The "global" command in vim will apply an ex command to every line that matches a certain regex. This can be restricted a certain range of lines, in this case 100-500. The regex here is

```
^[^ ]
```

Which means any character *except* for a space at the beginning of the line. The ex command is

```
normal 0ky^jP
```

What this does:

```
0           "Move to the first character on this line
 k          "Move up one line
  y^        "Yank up to the first non-whitespace character
    j       "Move down one line
     P      "Paste what we just yanked
```

After running this, just call

```
:wq
```

To save your file and quit. You could also do this all from the command line:

```
vim myfile.txt -c "100,500g/^[^ ]/normal 0ky^jP" -c "wq"
```

Another alternate solution:

```
:%s/\v^(\s+).*\n\zs(\S)/\1\2
```

Answer (score 0):

Homework? ;->

```
sed -e '100,500s/^[ ]*/        /' -i file
```

Comment: Wouldn't this indent all lines and not just the ones I want?

Comment: Yes, it would just add 8 spaces to the beginning of all lines, replacing any number of spaces currently present.